# Why python is "shy" to use memory in docker?

Tags: python, docker

I'm running a memory intensive python script (pandas, numpy, machine learning) in docker and performance is terrible.

In my host machine the script uses more than 10GB of RAM. The dockerized python script uses only 3Gb (com.docker.hyperkit process). I have already changer my docker memory preferences to 10gb (in Mac OS Docker GUI) and run the container with explicit memory limit:

```
docker run -m 10g ...
```

Why the container don't use 10gb as the host application does?

Comment: Since you mentioned Mac OS, there's going to be a VM involved. Try running the command inside that VM directly on the Docker host to narrow down whether the problem is the VM or the Docker container itself.

Comment: Note, there are various [older post](http://superuser.com/questions/507943/virtualbox-3584mb-memory-limit) about VirtualBox limited to 3.5G of memory in some configurations, so very likely your issue is with the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Computer programs use other resources besides memmory. There's CPU, I/O devices and information.
I would guess that this behavior you're seeing is the result of other resource been exausted. For instance, your I/O device could be causing a bottleneck before memmory is filled up. This is just a guess, because I have no other information.

Comment: Yes, i\o is one of the reason for the bad performance. But I'm sure that 3-times less memory is the major reason for the performance degradation (for this application).